# DLL inject replace a string at known offset C++

Tags: c++, assembly, dll, inject

Simple question, I'm not that great with c++ or the windows api but I managed to write a dll to inject. Basically I have the known memory offset of a line I would like to replace.

From IDA:
.text:0051CA30                 push    16D8h

From REC Decompile:
_push(5848);

5848 or 16D8h is nothing more than a value read from a file. All I want to do is hook the offset and print my own text. This should be very simple but I can't figure it out for the life of me and everything I try just keeps crashing the program. Replacing the text in the file isn't an option sadly as it could easy just be replaced and used to cheat.

I use detours for all the function replacements I have done just mentioning in case that helps.

Comment: Is there some reason you need to inject a DLL rather than writing to its memory with [`WriteProcessMemory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681674.aspx)?

Comment: I dont have to inject, but it will have to be in the same dll as my other injected functions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following snippet in your injected DLL if you want to replace a string in the target process.

```
char* buffer = reinterpret_cast<char*>(base + 0x16D8);
size_t length = strlen(buffer) + 1;

char myStr[length] = "...";

DWORD oldProtect;
VirtualProtect(buffer, length, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, &oldProtect);
memcpy(buffer, myStr, length);
VirtualProtect(buffer, length, oldProtect, nullptr);
```

**Note:** The length of the new string must be less than or equal to the original's.

Comment: If there might be code on the same page as the string (some compilers put read-only constants into the code segment), use PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, in case another thread executes code while you patch the string.

Comment: `the value of variable "length" cannot be used as a constant` ?